# how to get rid of computer lagging due to high page faults?

Tags: performance, windows-11

I'm experiencing some performance issues and when I googled it someone told me to check my page faults/sec. When I checked I noticed that the spikes in faults were directly correlated to when my computer would lag. I also noticed it doesn't really depend on uptime of the computer, whether I've just restarted or if it's been on for a day or two.

[This is a snapshot of my performance monitor track page faults/sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Zq6.png)
As you can see it peaks in the tens of thousands (I've seen as high as 70-80k), and my computer stutters, sometimes stopping my mouse from moving entirely, similar to client-side lag in a video game

[This is a snapshot of my resource monitor showing a consistant 0 hard faults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBHGF.png)
Im not sure exactly what this means, but I want to include as much information as possible

[This is process explorer showing the highest page faults per process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsL63.png)
This picture shows that the microsoft anti-malware, microsoft edge, and microsoft explorer are the biggest contributing factors to this problem.

I've tried switching browsers, that didn't help and im not sure what to try regarding the system processes.

[Lastly, a pic of system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKpK5.png)

- Windows 11 Home build 22621
- 32.0GB RAM
- Ryzen 5 3600X @ 4000Mhz

I am really at a loss here and don't know much about how to fix these kinds of issues, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: so PageFaults/s is useful in troubleshooting issues related to low memory or slow I/O, but with 32GB ram its unlikely you are doing a bunch of paging. That your mouse freezes makes me feel like its an OS kernel or low-level system application issue (could definitely be AV) but it doesn't seem like a issue with the hardware specs. maybe run a ram diagnostic, and check your harddisk SMART stats (and make sure your c:\ disk is not too full since that's where your page file is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soft** page faults are unlikely to be the actual cause of any stuttering you have. These page faults are normal, and occur whenever an application needs to read outside its active RAM. The number of faults/sec you're seeing is pretty normal for opening an application (I hit 90k opening excel for example).

On the other hand, **Hard** page faults require reading from your relatively slow hard drive and can cause serious stutters, even for just a small number. It doesn't look like you're seeing many of those, but I would still recommend checking whether you see high disk usage or latency when your PC stutters.

If windows defender is getting too aggressive, you can go into **Settings > Updates and Security > Windows Security > Virus and Threat Protection**, and toggle some of it off or schedule stuff like scans to run at different times, and see if that improves things.